# Read 8 bit data from LAN and display in GUI

Tags: c#, vb.net, sockets, lan

Hello I am an electrical engineering student and I am designing an equipment that records values and then sends it as simple 8 bit data to LAN port. I have to retrieve this data with timestamp and display it in a GUI.

Data sent will be in the form:

```
                (MSB)                                   (LSB)
             [start bit | 3 | 4 | 2 | 7 | 2 | 4 | 6 | stop bit]
```

And will be displayed in GUI as:

```
          [Computer Time]   34.2 Volts   7.2 Amperes   46 degrees
```

Please guide me as to how to access the imformation from LAN port using C# or VB.Net and if possible please post the socket programming because being an electrical engineer, programming is not really my forte. Thank you.

Comment: How are you sending the data? TCP? UDP?

Comment: As electrical engineering student, you should know something about the ISO/OSI model and then restate your question.

Comment: Data will be sent via UART if that's what you want to know.

Comment: UART is associated with serial data. You've asked for something LAN-related - implying Ethernet. They are not one and the same. Please could you clarify exactly how you're sending the data, and on what medium.

Comment: You seem to be using the term "bit" when you mean "byte", the data bits can't be '| 3 | 4 | 2 | 7 | 2 | 4 | 6 |'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking from experience, I wrote a packet analysis engine in C# for my university dissertation. The problem you will face is that Managed .NET does not allow you to capture data below the IP level, however there are some unmanaged API's you can use to gain access to lower level packet data. SharpPCap for example will allow you to capture packets at the Data Layer (Layer 2 in the OSI model). I know of nothing in .NET that will allow you to directly read/write bytes to the LAN adapter, and even if you could, any PC would probably discard it as erroneous bits/bytes.

My suggestions to you are:

1. Learn about the OSI model, and how packet encapsulation works.
2. Learn how MAC and IP addressing works
3. Consider at what level you can transmit your data, and how you are going to serialize it from code to something which is transmittable. (and vice-versa).

IMHO, this seems more like the job of a serial port, or maybe even USB, where you have greater control over the data being sent/received. LAN based systems are standards based, and therefore in order for your data to be acceptable, you will need to learn, to some extent, the standards, or use ready built implementations.

Comment: +1 for the advice, but to the OP I heartily recommend not even trying to go below the TCP/UDP level - no need for this. Instead try to implement some higher level protocol on top of TCP or UDP depending on your needs.

Comment: @tomfanning ...agreed, not a great idea to go low level with LAN, but sometimes necessary. The reason my packet analysis engine went so low level was so that I could detect things like ARP and DHCP etc heading for my router ...coming from a time when I was young and hackish! ;-)

Comment: I'm perfectly fine with using ready build implementations. And since the data from the equipment is being sent through an AVR microcontroller, I don't think there will be any IPs and MACs involved. Where can I get these ready build implementations?

Comment: @Asher, google "SharpPCap". This is what I used to allow packet sniffing at Ethernet / Data Layer of the OSI Model. You will also need WinPCap for this to work